# How is the argument understood at streams collect() in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<Currency, List<Transaction>> transactionsByCurrencies =transactions.stream().collect(groupingBy(Transaction::getCurrency));
```

Tyring to understand java-8 concepts!

`groupingBy` has been simply referred here. Is that a regular method or static method or lambda passing ?

How is `groupingBy` method understood by compiler here ?

Comment: here https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-collectors

Comment: Is there an `import static` declaration at the top?

Comment: If you would notice or define your `import`s, you would know it right there.

Comment: @Sweeper ok..got it.. may be was too busy going through the book.. didnt try on IDE !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`groupingBy` is a `static` method of the `Collectors` class.

In order to refer to it without the class name prefix, you need to add the proper import statement.