# How to create a list of distinct objects using list of different objects having properties using java streams

Tags: java, algorithm, java-stream, distinct

I have an algorythmic problem with creating something logical for a set of data like this:

```
|-------|--------|
|  id   | ctx_id |
|-------|--------|
|   1   |  1001  |
|   1   |  1002  |
|   1   |  1003  |
|   1   |  1004  |
|   2   |  2001  |
|   2   |  2002  |
|   2   |  2003  |
------------------
```

This is the list I get from the database, as an `List<UsersContexts>` object containing the `id` and `ctx_id`. What I want to achieve, is to create two objects of such entity:

```
private class UserData {
    private long id;
    private List<long> contextList;
}
```

Every user has an ID, and contexts assigned to him. What I want to achieve is to manipulate the data in table above so I can create two `UserData` object, the one containing `id = 1` and a list containg `1001, 1002, 1003, 1004`, and a second `UserData` object, containing `id = 2` and a list containing `2001, 2002, 2003`.

How can I achieve that? I tried using `filter()` on a `stream()` on this `List<UsersContexts>` object, but without effort...

Comment: Look into `groupingBy` for example as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60971820/how-is-the-argument-understood-at-streams-collect-in-java-8), just a while back. Give it a try and come write back here to edit the question if something doesn't work. As for now, this needs more focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to collect `UsersContexts` into `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>` using [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) grouping by on `id`. And then stream that map and convert each entry into `UserData`

```
    usersContexts.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(UsersContexts::getId, 
                         Collectors.mapping(UsersContexts::getCxtId, Collectors.toList())))
                 .entrySet()
                 .stream()
                 .map(entry->new UserData(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @dziki you can do with single stream.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` function and `toMap()` collectors with merge function.

```
Collectio<UserData> usersData = usersContexts.stream()
      .map(u -> new UserData(u.getId(), new ArrayList<>(singletonList(u.getCtx_id()))))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserData::getId, Function.identity(),
                 (o, o2) -> { o.getContextList().addAll(o2.getContextList());return o; }))
      .values();
```